# Check, if is allowed embedding ( youtube video ) PHP, new youtube API

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api, embed

can someone hep with replace old way to new YouTube API? 
I am looking for check option - allowed embedding.
My old code in PHP:

```
$url="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" . $videoID . "?v=2&alt=jsonc&prettyprint=true";
$json = file_get_contents($url, true);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
echo "emb = ".$json_output->data->accessControl->embed;
```

I am looking for easy, fast code, because i need to check more videos at time.
Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new base URL to get information about a video, through the ID, like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcdefghijkl is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=abcdefghijkl&key=YOUR_API_KEY&part={parts you want}
```

To get the status, if it's embaddable you have to set part to status, so your request looks like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=abcdefghijkl&key=YOUR_API_KEY&part=status
```

The response output will look something like this:

```
"status": {
   "uploadStatus": "processed",
   "privacyStatus": "public",
   "license": "youtube",
   "embeddable": true,
   "publicStatsViewable": true
 }
```

Source: [YouTube API - Getting started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) and [YouTube API - Reference Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)

I didn't test it, but I hope it will work and I could help you!

Comment: $url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=". $videoID ."&key=my_kez=y&part=status";
                                    $json = file_get_contents($url, true);
                                    $json_output = json_decode($json);
                                    echo "emb = ". $json_output->{'items'}[0]->{'status'}->{'privacyStatus'};      this is final correct .... thank Markus